# Are the switches for the SQLCMD command case sensitive?

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms, sqlcmd

I have MS SQL Server 2014 Management Studio installed on two computers, both of which run on Windows 10. The switches for `SQLCMD` command are case-sensitive on one computer, but it is not on the other one. If I type the command with lower case switches (like the below examples), it works on one but doesn't work on the other.

```
sqlcmd -s .\<_servername_>
sqlcmd -l
```

For the second computer, I have to type with upper case as shown below.

```
sqlcmd -S .\<servername>
sqlcmd -L
```

What is the issue/setting that decides this?

Comment: Are windows collations same on both computers ?
To get more info about sqlcmd switches, follow this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

Yes, SQLCMD switches are case sensitive.

```
 -l login_timeout  
 -L[c] (list servers, optional clean output)  
 -s col_separator  
 -S [protocol:]server[instance_name][,port]
```

When you connect using

```
sqlcmd -s .\<servername>
```

is connects to the default instance and uses `".\<servername>"` as column separator

While on the second machine there may not be any default instances so you need to enter `-S .\` explicitly to connect to a named instance

Comment: Please combine your two answers into one using the [edit] function. There's no need to split them in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect using

sqlcmd -s .\<*servername*>

is connects to the default instance and uses ".\<*servername*>" as column separator

While on the second machine there may not be any default instances so you need to enter 
-S .\ explicitly to connect to a named instance